# Check e-mail and password hash from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose, bcrypt

Implying I have an array containing E-mail and password combinations i.e.:

```
["john@doe.com", "johnspasswordhashhere", "janet@doe.com", "janetpasswordhashhere", "tim@doe.com", "timspasswordhashhere" ]
```

How do I compare whether the provided e-mail and password hash match? I need to use `bcrypt.compare(passtotestvar, passhash)` to compare.

Comment: Which part of that are you having a problem with, specifically?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't know what to use to check every second array element with

Comment: just loop every other element? i have trouble understanding what you mean

Comment: @GeestWagen how do I achieve that?

Comment: I do need to also check the password and E-mail as well, I don't know what logic should I implement..

Comment: You will first have to have the password hashed to check against. You can loop over each other element by using something like i % 2 === 0 on each loop.

Comment: @Munchkin `for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first sort the users and passwords, then loop over each user to check the credentials

```js
const arr = ["john@doe.com", "johnspasswordhashhere", "janet@doe.com", "janetpasswordhashhere", "tim@doe.com", "timspasswordhashhere"]
const sorted = arr.reduce((a, e, i) => (i % 2 || a.push([]), a[a.length - 1].push(e), a), [])
console.log(sorted)
```

Then you could use bcrypt's compare function, which does all the work for you:

```
// from DB
const users = {
  'john@doe.com': 'HASHEDPW',
  'janet@doe.com': 'HASHEDPW',
  'tim@doe.com': 'HASHEDPW'
}


sorted.forEach(([email, password]) => {
  bcrypt.compare(password, users[email]).then((e, r) => {
    // r = true if hash = hashed pw
  })
})
```

Comment: Won't bcrypt produce a different hash every time making a simple === check nonsensical?

Comment: No? If it created a different hash each time, then how are you supposed to use it in any useful way?

Comment: Just tested it out. The password "doe" produces `$2b$10$209PMqkYji90TGA1IUq/7eLoDvPDt/vblIlmBdb4I8gSxEzpxF18y` one time and `$2b$10$7rHMLs4cyKpxgDRPX.Q3vOGPARs.GRy3XTnLDlvA.klZ2VJXv9QiW` another time. Bcrypt always adds a salt into the hash

Comment: @Munchkin Ah yes my bad, I completely forgot about that, you're right. If there was no salt, I'm sure you would be able to, but not with bcrypt then.